# Why does one object value in a typescript array change without assigning a value?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have tried about a dozen different ways of asking this question, which does accurately describe my problem, but can't pass the "consider using a title that more accurately describes your question" checker. Maybe someone can help me retitle this?

Anyway, I have a method in typescript which manipulates the "position" value in an array of "WorkItem" objects - the method is as follows:

```
  static swapPositions(items: WorkItem[], i: number, j: number): WorkItem[] {
    console.log(items);
    console.log(items[i]);
    console.log(items[j]);
    console.log([i, j]);
    if (items.length >= 2) {
      console.log(items[i]);
      console.log(items[j]);
      console.log('i,j: ' + [items[i].position, items[j].position]);
      if (items[i].position === items[j].position) {
        if (items[i].position === 1) {
          items[j].position = 1;
          items[i].position = 2;
        } else if (items[j].position === items.length) {
          items[j].position = items[i].position - 1;
        } else {
          items[i].position = items[i].position + 1;
        }
      } else if (items[i].position < items[j].position) {
        const i_orig_pos = items[i].position;
        items[i].position = items[j].position;
        items[j].position = i_orig_pos;
      }
      console.log('i,j: ' + [items[i].position, items[j].position]);
    }
    items = Utils.swapArrayElements(items, i, j);
    console.log(items);
    return items;
  }
```

As you can see, I have liberally supplied console.log statements so that you can see the track of values. The problem seems to be near the top.

[image]

From the console: the i and j values are 0 and 1, respectively. What I don't understand is that in the first console log, you can see the position values for the first and second WorkItems as 1 and 1 (`console.log(items)`) and yet you can see the value in the second WorkItem object change from 1 to 2 (see the 3rd and 5th console.log statements - `console.log(items[j])`).

I can't see where I have assigned the value 2 to it, so something else must be happening, but I can't see it. I'm not sure if position is some kind of reserved word, but the linting in IntellJ isn't picking it up.

**EDIT** - I realized that with all the console.log statements in there, the code is a bit unclear, so I have reproduced it below without all those consoles:

```
  static swapPositions(items: WorkItem[], i: number, j: number): WorkItem[] {
    if (items.length >= 2) {
      if (items[i].position === items[j].position) {
        if (items[i].position === 1) {
          items[j].position = 1;
          items[i].position = 2;
        } else if (items[j].position === items.length) {
          items[j].position = items[i].position - 1;
        } else {
          items[i].position = items[i].position + 1;
        }
      } else if (items[i].position < items[j].position) {
        const i_orig_pos = items[i].position;
        items[i].position = items[j].position;
        items[j].position = i_orig_pos;
      }
    }
    items = Utils.swapArrayElements(items, i, j);
    return items;
  }
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

**EDIT**

This is the console output of the same lot of code, but with `JSON.stringify(xxx)` around each object as suggested by @jcalz

Also note that I changed "position" to "pos" on the possibility that position was some sort of reserved word.

[image]

Comment: But you *are* setting it? `items[i].position = 2;`  Is your issue that `console.log` doesn't produce a traversable snapshot of the state of the universe at the time the function was run?  That is, you are doing `console.log(someObject)`, and when you go look at `someObject` in the console it is showing you the *current* state of that object, which is *after* the code to change position was run.  If that is confusing you, try `console.log(items[whatever].position)` instead of `console.log(items[whatever]`).  Or maybe `console.log(JSON.stringify(items[whatever]))`

Comment: Yes, I am setting it, but quite a bit after the problem. Look closely at the first 6 console.log statements, particularly how `console.log(items[j])` changes. This is the area I am talking about. I just showed the whole method so that people could see the whole context.

Comment: You should invest some time in learning to use a debugger with breakpoints. This is,  for example, possible in VSCode, though you might need to install appropriate plugins for typescript and/or transpile to javascript using tsc. Console log is not always the best route to understanding..

Comment: I have done that. But I can't present the question clearly from a point of view of "trust me: these were the values that my debugger picked up" - but, trust me - this is what the debugger sees as well.

Comment: Yeah, I see... but I'm still not sure since I'm looking at images of console output and don't have it in front of me.  If you change all your `console.log` statements to print out a snapshot of the state like `JSON.stingify(thingYouAreLookingAt)` the same crazy jump in `items[1].position` from line 60 to line 61 occurs?

Comment: And can you reproduce this in a standalone example? Since this isn't a [mcve] it's almost impossible for anyone who isn't you to fix. ☹

Comment: I have added the `JSON.stingify(thingYouAreLookingAt)` changes and I'm astounded, the code actually works, when you're looking at the stringified logs. For a start, on entry pos is 1 and 2 rather than 1 and 1, and they do indeed swap, rather than stay on 1 and 1. So I guess my question is now - how am I getting two different results depending on how I log it? For the same reason, it may be hard now to provide that minimal, complete and verifiable example.